# Parsing different range integers in Xtext?

Tags: parsing, antlr, xtext

I'm new in xText, I installed a couple of days ago and this may look like a simple question but I haven't find a solution yet and I've being looking over Google a lot.

Basically I want to define an Assembly custom language.

Here's what I'm defining:

```
grammar org.comp.language.ASAWriter with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate aSAWriter "http://www.comp.org/language/ASAWriter"

ASAWriter :
(ModeloASA += Instructions)* 
;


Instructions:
    readInteger|readSmallInteger|readMediumInteger
    ;

readMediumInteger:
    'RMI' Register '-' MEDIUMINT ';'
;

readInteger:
    'RI' Register '-' INT ';'
;

readSmallInteger:
    'RSI' Register '-' SMALLINT ';'
;


Register:
'REG0'|'REG1'|'REG2'|'REG3'|'REG4'  
;


terminal SMALLINT:
    '1'|'2'|'3'
;

terminal MEDIUMINT:
    '1'|'2'|'3'|'4'|'5'|'6'|'7'|'8'|'9'|'10'
;
```

My problem is that when I enter the following:

```
RI REG0-2;
```

This should be a valid instruction,  (Operation Register-Integer), but I'm getting the following error:
mismatched input '2' expecting RULE_INT

Basically the problem is that the number '2' is consumed but SMALLINT instead of INT.

Any ideas on how to fix this? or if my approach is correct?

Answer (score 0):

The lexer operates independently of the parser. `2` will always be parsed as a `SMALLINT`, as that rule comes first.

Either handle it as a parser rule:

```
mediumint: SMALLINT_TOKEN | MEDIUMINT_TOKEN;

SMALLINT_TOKEN:
    '1'..'3'
;

MEDIUMINT_TOKEN:
    '4'..'10'
;
```

or don't handle it in your parser at all. Instead, parse all numbers as `int`s and then check in your abstract syntax tree/in your parsing logic if the number is too large.